Typo3 extending TCA do not work on Content Elements of type Flux
im trying to extend the tca (frame_class) and add new items to the select list every time i user chose one of my items an input element of type text should appear so what using the regular steps
this is what i did
1- create an new file tt_content at this path extensions\site\Configuration\TCA\Overrides\tt_content.php
2- put some code into it
// debug($GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']);die();
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['frame_class'] = [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:frame_class',
            'onChange'=>'reload',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                'items' => [
                    ['label' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:frame_class.default', 'value' => 'default'],
                    ['label' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:frame_class.ruler_before', 'value' => 'ruler-before'],
                    ['label' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:frame_class.ruler_after', 'value' => 'ruler-after'],
                    ['label' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:frame_class.indent', 'value' => 'indent'],
                    ['label' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:frame_class.indent_left', 'value' => 'indent-left'],
                    ['label' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:frame_class.indent_right', 'value' => 'indent-right'],                
                    ['label' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:frame_class.none', 'value' => 'none'],
                    ['label'=>'Custom Section Class','value'=>'Section'],
                    ['label'=>'Custom Class','value'=>'Class']
                ],
                'default' => 'default',
            ],
        ];

// Add the new field custom_section to tt_content
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tt_content', [
    'custom_section' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'Custom Section Class Name',
        'description' => 'Section class name',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 30,
            'eval' => 'trim',
            'behaviour' => [
                'allowLanguageSynchronization' => true,
            ],
        ],
        'displayCond' => 'FIELD:frame_class:=:Section', // Show only if frame_class is 'Section'
    ],
]);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('tt_content', 'custom_section', '', 'after:frame_class');

// Add the new field custom_class to tt_content
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tt_content', [
    'custom_class' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'Class Name',
        'description' => 'class name',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 30,
            'eval' => 'trim',
            'behaviour' => [
                'allowLanguageSynchronization' => true,
            ],
        ],
        'displayCond' => 'FIELD:frame_class:=:Class', // Show only if frame_class is 'Class'
    ],
]);

// Add the new field to the palettes and show items
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('tt_content', 'custom_class', '', 'after:frame_class');


3- add the new fields to the ext_table.sql
CREATE TABLE tt_content (
    custom_class varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    custom_section varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
);

4- Analyze Database Structure and clear the cache
this work fine for all Ctypes only the Ctypes of type flux. any help ?

as far as I know flux elements are saved as FlexForms, and therefore have no distinct fields in the table tt_content or any other table. So they are saved in the database, but all flux-fields all together in one single database field as XML.

so according to you, flux should not override my configuration, so whats the problem then ?

Are you aware of the order of loading the extensions? In composer-based instances, you must define your (site-)packages dependencies properly ...  If flux is loaded after your package, you might not be able to modify TCA flux will add later.

yes im aware of that but dosen't matter if its last or first still not working
composer.json=>
"require": {
"oussema/site": "^1.0",
"fluidtypo3/flux": "^10.0",
"fluidtypo3/vhs": "^7.0",
"georgringer/news": "^11.4",
"in2code/powermail": "^12.3",
...

No. Your oussema/site has to require the packages it is extending, not your root-composer.json. So flux is loaded before oussema/site, because the latter requires flux.
